# Android mystery: thread disappears?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity that creates a worker thread for transitioning a picture in a list of pictures. Yes, in onPause()/onResume() I start and stop the worker thread. Skipping to the meat of the worker, I have a loop that ends when it is interrupted and the main variable is set to null (or another worker):

```
    public void run()
    {
        while(transitionWorkerThread == this)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.d(getLogTag(), "Ready to sleep.");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Log.d(getLogTag(), "ready to transition, is running? " + (transitionWorkerThread == this));
                if(transitionWorkerThread == this)
                {
                    Log.d(getLogTag(), "ready to post image change");
                    MAIN_THREAD_HANDLER.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Log.d(getLogTag(), "ready to go to next image");
                                    imageSlideView.goNextImage();
                                    Log.d(getLogTag(), "supposedly went to next image");
                                }
                            });
                    Log.d(getLogTag(), "posted image change, is running? " + (transitionWorkerThread == this));
                }
            }
            catch(final InterruptedException interruptedException)
            {
                Log.d(getLogTag(), "Worker interrupted.");
            }
            catch(final Throwable throwable)
            {
                Log.d(getLogTag(), "some sort of picture error?", throwable);
            }
        }
        Log.d(getLogTag(), "dropped out of picture loop, worker: " + transitionWorkerThread + " is us? " + (transitionWorkerThread == this));
    }
```

Now here's the mystery: the thread disappears! It just stops executing after a while! Seriously! Look at this log output:

```
11-22 13:13:40.186: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): Ready to sleep.
11-22 13:13:40.191: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to go to next image
11-22 13:13:40.191: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): supposedly went to next image
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to transition, is running? true
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to post image change
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): posted image change, is running? true
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): Ready to sleep.
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to go to next image
11-22 13:13:45.253: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): supposedly went to next image
11-22 13:13:50.272: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to transition, is running? true
11-22 13:13:50.272: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to post image change
11-22 13:13:50.272: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to go to next image
11-22 13:13:50.272: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): supposedly went to next image
11-22 13:13:50.301: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): posted image change, is running? true
11-22 13:13:50.301: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): Ready to sleep.
11-22 13:13:55.325: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to transition, is running? true
11-22 13:13:55.325: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to post image change
11-22 13:13:55.325: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to go to next image
11-22 13:13:55.325: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): supposedly went to next image
11-22 13:13:55.331: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): posted image change, is running? true
11-22 13:13:55.331: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): Ready to sleep.
11-22 13:14:00.011: E/dalvikvm(76): No free temp registers
11-22 13:14:00.011: E/dalvikvm(76): Jit: aborting trace compilation, reverting to interpreter
11-22 13:14:00.365: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to transition, is running? true
11-22 13:14:00.365: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to post image change
11-22 13:14:00.365: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): ready to go to next image
11-22 13:14:00.365: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): supposedly went to next image
11-22 13:14:00.371: D/PictureFrameActivity(941): posted image change, is running? true
11-22 13:14:06.042: D/dalvikvm(941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2106K, 58% free 3260K/7751K, external 13519K/13938K, paused 15ms+10ms
11-22 13:14:06.541: I/dalvikvm(941): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
11-22 13:14:11.111: D/dalvikvm(941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2051K, 57% free 3342K/7751K, external 13519K/13938K, paused 19ms+17ms
11-22 13:14:15.121: D/dalvikvm(941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2174K, 59% free 3216K/7815K, external 13519K/13938K, paused 20ms+20ms
11-22 13:14:19.271: D/dalvikvm(941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2028K, 59% free 3235K/7815K, external 13519K/13938K, paused 24ms+21ms
```

You'll notice after the last "posted image change, is running? true", the thread just goes away and is never heard from again! Looking at the code, there are only a few choices: I could see "Worker interrupted" or "some sort of picture error" or even "dropped out of picture loop". If everything goes OK, it should loop back around and say "Ready to sleep."

But I don't see anything else from this thread! It is as if it has been suspended at the end of a loop. Surely Android doesn't just pause a thread. This is a mystery.

*Update:* I've taken the whole worker thread out and put it in a separate local service being called by the activity. The worker thread still just disappears after a few loops. That's crazy---a worker thread is a common use for services. Something fishy is going on... but I'd still appreciate someone giving me a clue as to what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! This wasn't a thread issue at all. This was my fault (surprise!).

I wasn't completely truthful about the original code. It actually looked like this:

```
final long sleepLength = transitionIntervalManager.pollState();
try
{
    Log.d(getLogTag(), "Ready to sleep for "+sleepLength);
    Thread.sleep(sleepLength);
```

This `transitionIntervalManager` is a fancy class I've written to actually slow the transitions down over time. I had a bug so that, when it gets to the last (slowest) transition time, calling `pollState` would go into an endless loop and never return. Because that method was called before the first log, the log would never get written---and my thread would still be churning away trying to get the next transition. (No wonder my laptop fan came on!)

I tried to simplify the code, and I didn't realize I was simplifying away the problem---I mean, how could such a simple piece of code have bugs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your thread is being killed but my guess is it is related to activity lifecycle. Now in Android there is a nice class that is meant to allow for easy threading and periodically posting something back to the UI thread like your code does. Look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use the [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) function to update your UI objects. Again I am not sure what is wrong with your code but best practice for Android threading is to use this class.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is what is recommended in this case? First of all, an AsyncTask is built on threads, just as my thread is. Second of all, AsyncTasks are pulled from a pool of threads---do we really want its background method to sleep every few seconds and basically last forever, depriving the pool of the AsyncTask? And lastly, how do we know my thread is being killed? Where can one find documentation indicating that Android would simply kill a thread, without interrupting it and providing nothing in the log to indicate it did so? And how would an AsyncTask prevent this?